# Keycloak SMTP configuration with Google Workspaces

Tags: smtp, gmail, keycloak, google-workspace

I'm setting up the SMTP server on my keycloak instance.
I tried with my Gmail account, just to see if it works. I generated applications credentials following [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833). It worked nicely.

Now, I want to use the SMTP relay mode on my Google Workspace account, which has a specific domain. [Google recommends](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en). It works on other apps I have, but I could not make it work with Keycloak. There is no place to put the `Domain` so I don't even know if it's possible.

I searched the internet. [This guy](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/cant-send-mails-with-gsuite-relay-smtp/1946) encountered my issue, but I think he solved it by doing it with applications credentials as I did in the beginning.

The thing is, I'd prefer not use application credentials because that would link my app to a Google User. I could create a dedicated one, but it would be a monthly cost. The SMTP relay solution seemed the perfect way, until I could not make it work.

Is there something I miss ? Maybe another way to use Google's SMTP server ?

Thank you for reading
Antoine

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: Just for others who did not find "App Password" in the Account Security after enabling 2FA in an Account created with Google Workspace: You have to click on "2 Factor Authentication" to see the "App Password" section where you can create such. (assuming, SMTP relay as asked in the question does not work with Keycloak)